# How to ignore some files for GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I just need not to run all the files that I have in the dir, but I don't know what command should I use.

This is the command I use, but it changes ALL the files that I have inside of the dir, not only which I want...

```
parallel --plus echo data path: {} and fullname ID: {/..} VS digit-only ID: "{= s/.*\\/ABC\^//; s/-.*// =}" ::: ${WORKING_DIR}/*
```

I tried with regex as a replacement, but it didn't work.

> Example files:

- 10
- 20
- 30
- 40
- TXT---> I don't want to read this file with Parallel from the dir.

How can I omit this file from the others in Bash shell?

Thank you so much!

Read only the files I want in GNU Parallel.

Comment: soo `${WORKING_DIR}/[1-9][1-9]`? It is just a glob.

Comment: Bash's "extended globbing" feature provides powerful ways to generate filtered lists of files.  For instance, `!(TXT)` will expand to all the files in the current directory except a file called `TXT`.  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Answer (score 1):

It seems more a question for Bash than GNU Parallel. But you might be able to use `skip`:

```
touch {1..10} foo.txt bar.cfg
parallel echo '{= /txt|cfg/ and skip =}' ::: *
```

This will make GNU Parallel skip the job, if the input matches **txt** or **cfg**.